# Is there any way of knowing who [including remote users] can access a paticular file / folder?

Tags: users, group, remote-management, remote-control

In Windows you could enter file properties and see which users have an access to a particular files. [Including remote users / groups that are part of your domain]

In unix when you enter properties of a file - You only get the local users[Or groups] / Owner / Others. Is there any way of knowing which remote users have access to a particular files? [Is there anything 'built-in' unix?]

My current solution is using 'last' command. [Remote users which entered a local user have to have at least the local user permissions] But this solution only works if the user actively logged in to the system. Which means I miss every remote user that didn't log into the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends entirely on what mechanism you're using.

NFS with `sys` authentication purely relies on the user/group/other permissions and UID/GID matching. So you have to figure out 'by hand' whether any given user is a member of the right group.

Remote users ... are validated by the server hosting the storage, so you can simply refer to your local name lookup. E.g. ldap, local groups files, etc. So you can usually do this by the simple expedient of running the `id` command `id $username` to see memberships. Depending on precisely what you have configured locally, something like `getent group $group_name` will show you group members from LDAP. (Or just read `/etc/groups` if that's your auth source)

If you're looking for something more potent, you can start to look towards NFSv4 and Kerberos, which allow for more detailed (CIFS-like) ACLs and stronger (E.g. 'domain level' authenticated) user authentication.